# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined using redux and Django Rest Framework to Pull Data

Tags: reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, react-redux, react-hooks

I have already checked answers of this type of question but I am unable to reproduce the solution.

Problematic Code :

`AboutUs.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col, Card, Container, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
// import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Paginate from '../components/Paginate'
import { listAboutUs } from '../actions/aboutUsActions'

function AboutUs() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const aboutUsList = useSelector(state => state.aboutUsList)
    const { error, loading, about} = aboutUsList

    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listAboutUs())

    }, [dispatch])
    return (
        <div>
            {loading ? <Loader />
                : error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
                    :
                    <div>
                       
                        <Container variant='success'>
                    
                            {about.map(item => (
                                <Col key={item._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                                    
                                    <Card style={{minWidth:'auto', maxWidth:'auto'}}   >
                                    
                                    </Card>
                                    
                                    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' ,  height: '30rem'}} className= "card border-success mb-2 my-0 p-2 rounded">
                                        <Card.Header>ID : {item._id}</Card.Header>
                                        <Card.Body>CardBody</Card.Body>
                                    </Card>

                                </Col>
                            ))}
                        
                       
                        </Container>
                    </div>
                    
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default AboutUs
```

relative reducer

```
import {
    ABOUT_LIST_REQUEST,
    ABOUT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    ABOUT_LIST_FAIL, } from '../constants/aboutConstants'


export const aboutUsListReducer = (state = { about: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ABOUT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true, about: [] }

        case ABOUT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                about: action.payload.about,
            }

        case ABOUT_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

`aboutUsActions.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {
    ABOUT_LIST_REQUEST,
    ABOUT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    ABOUT_LIST_FAIL, } from '../constants/aboutConstants'

export const listAboutUs = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: ABOUT_LIST_REQUEST })

        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/branding/about/`)

        dispatch({
            type: ABOUT_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: ABOUT_LIST_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
                ? error.response.data.detail
                : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

`store.js`

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

import {
    aboutUsListReducer,
    
} from './reducers/aboutUsReducers'

const reducer = combineReducers({
    aboutUsList: aboutUsListReducer,
})

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : []

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userInfo') ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) : null


const shippingAddressFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress') ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress')) : {}


const initialState = {
    cart: {
        cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage,
        shippingAddress: shippingAddressFromStorage,
    },
    userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
    
}

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store
```

there are other reducers in store as well but included relevent one

`api endpoint`
`http://localhost:8000/api/branding/about/`

I have used same approach in other models in to get data from Django Rest Api, they are working fine , but I don't know why this is happening this time. Kindly tell me what I m doing wrong or what could be the other related possible way to solve this issue.

API working fine but I m including `views.py`

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getAboutUs(request):
    about = AboutUs.objects.all()
    serializer = AboutUsSerializer(about, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

complete error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
AboutUs
E:/eCommerce_Projects/remote-hospital/frontend/src/screens/AboutUs.js:28
  25 | :
  26 | <div>
  27 |    
> 28 |     <Container variant='success'>
     | ^  29 | 
  30 |         {about.map(item => (
  31 |             <Col key={item._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
View compiled
▶ 24 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
E:/eCommerce_Projects/remote-hospital/frontend/src/actions/aboutUsActions.js:13
  10 | 
  11 |        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/branding/about/`)
  12 | 
> 13 |        dispatch({
     | ^  14 |            type: ABOUT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  15 |            payload: data
  16 |        })
View compiled
```

Answer (score 1):

In aboutUs.js on line 30

Try doing

`{Array.isArray(about) && about.map(…)}`

Simple explanation: you are most likely trying to map over sn undefined value. This is usually caused by race conditions between the http call and the render method

Another solution would be to initialise the vslue about as sn array like `about = []` and make sure the value of about remains an array throughout the life cycle of the component

Update:

```
{loading ? <Loader />
                : error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
                    :
                    <div>
                       
                        <Container variant='success'>
                    
                            {Array.isArray(about) && about.map(item => (. <———————
                                <Col key={item._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                                    
                                    <Card style={{minWidth:'auto', maxWidth:'auto'}}   >
                                    
                                    </Card>
                                    
                                    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' ,  height: '30rem'}} className= "card border-success mb-2 my-0 p-2 rounded">
                                        <Card.Header>ID : {item._id}</Card.Header>
                                        <Card.Body>CardBody</Card.Body>
                                    </Card>

                                </Col>
                            ))}
                        
                       
                        </Container>
                    </div>
                    
            }
```

Comment: Where to put that line `{Array.isArray(about) && about.map(…)} ` I m not very sure about this method

Comment: Here: e:/eCommerce_Projects/remote-hospital/frontend/src/screens/AboutUs.js:30

Comment: Yes I know it belongs to that file but how, There's if statement in the code if we put in there then 5 types of more comes on like syntax errors .

Comment: Can you make changes in `AboutUs.js file ` and if you add them into your answer ?

Comment: I changed this way `{Array.isArray(about) && about.map(item => ( ...`  that removed the error but not getting the desired data.

Comment: Request is hitting the server with 200 status code `[25/Jun/2021 23:30:22] "GET /api/branding/about/ HTTP/1.1" 200 281` but why not displaying the data